# WebBrowsing in C# - Libraries, Tools etc. - Anything like Mechanize in Perl?

Tags: c#, authentication, screen-scraping, mechanize

Looking for something similar to Mechanize for .NET...

If you don't know what Mechanize is.. http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/

I will maintain a list of suggestions here.  Anything for browsing/posting/screen scraping (Other than WebRequest and WebBrowser Control).

**Parsing**

- HTMLAgilityPack - http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack

**Web App Testing**

- WatiN - Web Application Testing Framework (.NET) - http://watin.sourceforge.net/
- Selenium - http://seleniumhq.org/
- Art of Test Design Canvas - Costs Money

**Tools**

- Firebug for Firefox
- Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar for IE
- Chrome has one too

**Note**

WatiN is close to what I am looking for, except it opens up a browser, which is annoying and awesome at the same time.  Depends on what you are doing.

Comment: In WatiN, just set "IE.Settings.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible" property to false, and take a look at "IE.Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher". More info on http://www.watin.net

Comment: Just call perl from c#, there's nothing like web mechanize in .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) to great effect.   It's an easy way to 1) automate user input w/ IE and 2) navigate the DOM.

Comment: WatiN requires actually launching browser windows. Mechanize is in-memory only

Comment: It is a bit slow, but it is fun to watch the browser be automated.   Even more fun is to call .Highlight on whichever part of the DOM you're processing, and you can watch the processing happen.

Comment: Another benefit of WatiN - since it interacts with IE, it can process the *live* DOM - that is, there's no problem if the page been built by javascript.   I don't believe the HTML agility pack can do that.

Comment: @qntmfred: You can hide those windows: "IE.Settings.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false". There is another property which handles dialogs: "IE.Settings.AutoStartDialogWatcher".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `WebBrowser` control, which can be automated to an extent.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack), which can parse tag soup from real websites into a DOM structure.

Comment: That's good for parsing the pages once you get them, but what about everything else?  Like, logging into sites, managing cookies, handling redirection etc?

Comment: Use the `WebClient` class, or HAP's `HtmlWeb` class, or the `HttpWebRequest` class with a `CookieContainer`.

Comment: I know you can do it that way in .NET, looking for something a little higher level.  Like Mechanize.  Its OK if there isn't one, I just was curious if there was a library that did what I have done using WebClient etc.

Comment: A friend of mine wrote a program that does what my C# program does using Mechanize, and it is 13 lines.  Mine is WAY more.  13 LINES! =P

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).  It's for unit testing web sites.  It has a java application that drives the browser and a C# interface that you can write your code in.  It also has the downside of showing the browser, but it's pretty full featured in terms of control, waiting on responses and getting the results.

Answer (score 1):

[Design Canvas](http://www.artoftest.com) is the best tool out there for this type of thing. Works with IE, Firefox, Safari, or an in-memory browser. It allows you to record and then playback any kind of web interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You want [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) for automating web requests and [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) for processing the resulting HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I have reverse engineered Python-Mechanize, and recreated it in C#, called Mechanize.NET.

https://github.com/WilliamABradley/Mechanize.NET

This should hopefully cover all use cases of Mechanize, if not, or you discover a bug, create an issue.

It uses .NET Standard, so it should be usable across .NET, such as with F#, VB, etc.

It utilises HtmlAgilityPack internally, and you can even collect the HtmlDocument for each loaded page.