# Ajax simulating a click

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can someone let me know if this is possible with Ajax. I want to load an external site onto a page and then use jQuery, jScript, php, or some method to simulate a click on the external site page that I just loaded up.

The site will not allow the traditional post / get

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    function FriendCenterObject() {
        var fcAction = function(actionUrl, gamerTag, responseHandler) {
            responseHandler = responseHandler || function(response) {
                if (response.status != 0) {
                    DisplayMessageDialog('Error', response.view, 'Close', null, MessageLevelType.Error);
                }
                else {
                    DisplayMessageDialog('Message', response.view, 'Close', FriendCenter.RefreshContentAction);
                }
            }
            $.post(actionUrl, { 'gamerTag': gamerTag }, responseHandler);
        };
        this.AddFriend = function(gamerTag) {
            gamerTag = $.trim(gamerTag); // trim leading and trailing whitespaces
            if (gamerTag != "") {
                fcAction('/en-US/FriendCenter/SendFriendRequest', gamerTag);
            }
            return false;
        };
        this.RefreshContentAction = function(){};
    };
    var FriendCenter = new FriendCenterObject();
//]]>
</script>
```

and this is the link i want users to be able to click

```
<a href="#" onclick="FriendCenter.AddFriend('mirco')">Add to Friends List</a>
```

I did some more investagating and its definitely using Post method with a content type of Content-Type:application/json

Comment: This will require a little more detail to answer. You are "loading" an external site onto a page which contains your script — is this through an `iframe`, or some sort of AJAX request?

Comment: Is it within your domain? Because if it's not, you shouldn't be able to. If you need to automate clicks of external sites, you could look into http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: This might be of use to you.  I used it when I needed to do something similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149867/webbrowsing-in-c-libraries-tools-etc-anything-like-mechanize-in-perl

Comment: please see above i've added the section of the coding from the external page that I'm trying to allow the user to click.

Answer (score 1):

I would say its very simple. Simply use `$.ajax()` to get the page, and then put it on the DOM (By selecting a container element and using `.html()` or `.append()` on it, adding what ajax returns.  After that, select the item you wish to click (which is now in your DOM) and call `.click()`.  If you need specific examples, give code.

Comment: Note the 'external' part of the question. Xhr wont work x-browser to external domains.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the site with:

```
jQuery("#iframeID").src = "path/to/site";
```

After loading external site into iFrame, you can try:

```
//getting the content window html tag.
var iFrame = document.getElementById("iframeID").contentWindow;
jQuery(iFrame.body).find("#someID").click();
```

Comment: if the document is from another domain you can't do that.

Comment: when the document is on another domain its just not possible with jquery, php, ajax, etc. correct?