# POST to Json webervice is returning Error 500

Tags: c#, json, web-services, post

I have standard asmx webservice returning Json:

```
private void ReturnUser(string name)
{
    User user = new User(name);
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, @object);
    string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    stream.Close();

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("ContentType", "application/json");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(jsonString);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

On the other side, I want to try that webservice is running, so I try call the POST:

```
string data = "name=test";
byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://tempuri.org/External.asmx?op=ReturnUser");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
reqStream.Close();
WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
stream.Close();
reader.Close();

Console.Write(json);
Console.Read();
```

But I get Error 500. From browser is the webservice running like a charm :(

Comment: the error 500 is sometimes caused by error's on your .asmx methods. check also the authentication used.

Comment: Just curious but why are you manually serializing this to JSON and writing directly to the response? You should be able to add this to the method if it is an ASMX service and get a JSON response from the return value:  [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

Comment: I tried to use [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] but it returned XML. Only later I read it is working only with AJAX or jQuery, but I' intended to call it from non-.net mobile device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this, may be this helps to someone else:

```
string data = "name=test";
byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://tempuri:org/External.asmx/ReturnUser");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
stream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
stream.Close();
reader.Close();
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

On many servers, 500 series errors are security or permissions errors.  Since you are getting the 500 error, you are at least getting full connectivity to the server.

Obviously, your code is never being called since it cannot generate the 500 error--so the server layers you depend on are doing it.  That smells like permissions or security.

The server should be sending back text that tells what is happening.  Check the response body for more information.  It may also have local logging that helps.

I had to solve a similar problem with .NET code.  I needed to get information via HTTP from a server, but it required authentication.  I couldn't use any of the integrated security methods like Kerberos or Basic Authentication because the server I had used cookie based (sometimes called forms based) authentication.

If you have that issue, this might help:
[.NET - Consuming HTTP services on (Domino) server with form based authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731857/net-consuming-http-services-on-domino-server-with-form-based-authentication)

My server was Domino, but the idea applies to any HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://tempuri.org/External.asmx");
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/ReturnUser\"");
```

Answer (score -1):

Websevices require form action value explicitly specified with the POST request. So, please try to add form "action" url to your POST request.